# How do you shoot a bullet towards mouse in pygame at a constant speed?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to shoot a bullet towards my mouse in pygame, here is my code:

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

pygame.display.set_caption("diep.io")

screen.fill((255,255,255))

auto_shoot = False

class Bullet:
  def __init__(self, x_move, y_move, x_loc, y_loc):
    self.image = pygame.image.load("Bullet.png")
    self.x_move = x_move
    self.y_move = y_move
    self.x_loc = x_loc
    self.y_loc = y_loc
    self.bullet_rect = self.image.get_rect()
  
  def update(self):
    self.bullet_rect.center = (self.x_loc + self.x_move, self.y_loc + self.y_move)
    self.x_loc = self.bullet_rect.center[0]
    self.y_loc = self.bullet_rect.center[1]
    screen.blit(self.image, self.bullet_rect)

    if self.x_loc > 400 or self.y_loc > 400:
      bullets.remove(self)

bullet = None
bullets = []

while True:
  screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (100, 100, 100), (205, 193, 25, 15))
  pygame.draw.circle(screen, (82, 219, 255), (200, 200), 15)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
      x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - 200
      y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - 200
      pythag = float(math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))
      bullets.append(Bullet(x/pythag, y/pythag, 200, 200))
  for bullet in bullets:
    bullet.update()
  pygame.display.update()
  pygame.time.delay(10)
```

I am confused on how to make this work, I think somehow I am rounding something, but even after I put float() in, it still is not working. Also, before when I used the mouse coordinates, it works, but when close to tank, it shoots slow, and insanely fast farther from the tank. Somebody please help, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the coordinates gets lost when the new position of the object is assigned to the *Rect* object.
You have to do it the other way around. Change `self.x_loc` and `self.y_loc`, but update `self.bullet_rect.center`:

```py
class Bullet:
  # [...]

  def update(self):
    self.x_loc += self.x_move
    self.y_loc += self.y_move   
    self.bullet_rect.center = round(self.x_loc), round(self.y_loc)

    rect = screen.blit(self.image, self.bullet_rect)
    if not screen.get_rect().contains(rect):
      bullets.remove(self)
```

See also these questions:
[Shooting a bullet in pygame in the direction of mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977052/shooting-a-bullet-in-pygame-in-the-direction-of-mouse/59980344#59980344) and [How can you rotate the sprite and shoot the bullets towards the mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126785/how-can-you-rotate-the-sprite-and-shoot-the-bullets-towards-the-mouse-position/59126918#59126918).